# Efficient data sharing between Java and C using JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm trying to access a C struct within Java code. I know there are various techniques to do this but I'm looking for the most efficient in terms of minimising methods calls between languages (through the JNI) and reducing memory copies.

I had the idea of passing a ByteBuffer pointer from Java to C, and putting C struct pointers within the ByteBuffer. Then, from the Java side I could access the data from the C struct using direct memory access and parse the variables into a Java class. Is something like this possible and can somebody please start me off?

Are there any better/faster techniques for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to use the JNA (Java Native Access) project on Github to easily call C from Java.  It works well, and I also noticed that they have a discussion of how to access C structures from Java.  Take a look on this page (scroll down for the README):

[JNA project on Github](https://github.com/twall/jna)

and linking from that page, their *Getting Started* document gives details and examples of accessing and passing C structures:

[Getting Started with JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md)